# Importing a file with "," as delimiter

Tags: c#, datagridview

The file im trying to read is looking like this:

123,123,123h123m,123,123,123

And I have following code to try to read that:

```
public DataTable DataTableFromTextFile(string location, char delimiter = ',')
{
    DataTable result;

    string[] LineArray = File.ReadAllLines(path);

    result = FormDataTable(LineArray, delimiter);

    return result;
}

private static DataTable FormDataTable(string[] LineArray, char delimiter)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    AddColumnToTable(LineArray, delimiter, ref dt);

    AddRowToTable(LineArray, delimiter, ref dt);

    return dt;
}

private static void AddRowToTable(string[] valueCollection, char delimiter, ref DataTable dt)
{

    for (int i = 1; i < valueCollection.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] values = valueCollection[i].Split(delimiter);
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
        {
            dr[j] = values[j];
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}

private static void AddColumnToTable(string[] columnCollection, char delimiter, ref DataTable dt)
{
    string[] columns = columnCollection[0].Split(delimiter);
    foreach (string columnName in columns)
    {
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(columnName, typeof(string));
    }
}
```

but it does not seem to work yet. I have tried changing some things but it then went to adding blank spaces into the DataGridView (which is called infoTabelle).
Anyone able to help me fix my problem?

****EDIT
Got it all fixed now. I changed the method where it was to put my seperated text into the DataGridView. Working like a charm now.**

Comment: What errors do you get? "does not seem to work" will get you nowhere here on SO. And welcome by the way! I'd recommend to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: BTW: `ref DataTable dt` - why do you think the `ref` is needed here?

Comment: Add some unit tests to your code to ensure that each individual method works as expected. Test splitting and verifying the DataTable separately. Do you even get a valid DataTable from this?

Comment: I did add some debug points, it read the file without any problems but couldnt add it to the DataGridView. I got it all fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like this:

```
// Simple: quotation "..." e.g. "123,456",789 is not implemented 
private static DataTable FromCsvSimple(string path, char delimiter = ',') {
  // Try avoiding ReadAllLines; use ReadLines
  // Where - let's skip empty lines (if any)
  var lines = File
    .ReadLines(path)
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    .Select(line => line.Split(delimiter));

  DataTable result = new DataTable();

  foreach (string[] items in lines) {
    // Do we have any columns to add?
    for (int c = 0; c < items.Length; ++c) 
      while (c >= result.Columns.Count)
        result.Columns.Add();

    result.Rows.Add(items);
  }

  return result;
}

...

DataTable myTable = FromCsvSimple(@"c:\MyCsv.csv", ';');
```